# Dashboard--> All Pages "How to create folders?"

Tags: pages, admin, dashboard

I have going on three pages in All Pages on my Dashboard. Is there a way I can set up folders for these pages - - it's becoming a confusing "mess" to find which page I need to update when - for example - on PayPal I had to create separate thank you pages per button. With multiple currencies, each needing a separate button and eBooks are non-taxable, whereas books are taxed, its getting confusing...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are no page folders in WordPress, though that's a good idea.

Create subpages; that will give you a visual hierarchy, an also an automatic "breadcrumb" hierarchy, if useful. But you will still be able to organize pages in menus any way you want. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

And/or use CMS Page Tree View http://wordpress.org/plugins/cms-tree-page-view/

And Simple Page Ordering http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-page-ordering/ could be useful, too.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this ability too and found that there is now a plugin called Folders - for those needing that functionality.

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/folders/

Description

Folders gives you the ability to better organise the back-end of your WordPress site by allowing you to add pages, posts and media attachments into folders. You can then filter your pages, posts and media by the folder they belong to from within the admin sidebar. A handy plugin for those with lots of pages or posts and a whole lot of media.

Answer (score 0):

Wicked Folders is another plugin that does what you're describing (i.e. organize pages into folders) and it's free on WordPress.org.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wicked-folders/